# Can Nokogiri interpret javascript? - Web Scraping

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

We are trying to scrape the availabilities on this page:
http://www.equityapartments.com/new-york/new-york-city-apartments/midtown-west/mantena-apartments.aspx

I need to use my spider to select on the "All Floorplans" and fetch all the availabilities. But the data are actually sent through Javascript request I believe. Is there a way for my Nokogiri spider to render it? Or maybe simulate the process of clicking on buttons?

Answer (score 14):

[Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) is just a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser). It also allows to search content.

To interact with web pages you need to use something else, e.g. [Watir](http://watir.com/) and [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Combining them all together:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs)

browser.goto(your_url_above)
browser.link(text: 'All floorplans').click

document = Nokogiri::HTML(browser.html)
document.search(...)
```

Comment: Using `gem install watir phantomjs` and trying your snippet, I get a `/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require': cannot load such file -- selenium/webdriver/phantomjs (LoadError)` error. It also spits out a warning about Selenium support for PhantomJS being deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it if the Floorplans have an id/class. You can get those from your page.

You will be needing [firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/eN-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) to help you get the XPath of the elements and then you can iterate them using it. For example, recently I worked on [webpagescraper](https://github.com/mike1011/webpagescraper/tree/master/webpagescraper) to scrape HTML from [fundly.com](https://fundly.com/search/%60).

To get all titles, as all `titles` elements in the HTML had the same class, I was able to get EVERY title on https://fundly.com/search/%60 using that XPath with the class name like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc.search('h4.f-width-100').each do |title|
   @campaign_titles <<  title.text
end
```

Please refer to my above project if you need any more assistance to grab the values from any website.

Comment: Please take the time to use correct grammar and spelling in your answers. Failing to do so forces us to do it for you which takes away from our time to help others.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan,will take care next time :)